# Make Jquery\Javascript more Efficient

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code to generate an select list on the fly. The code works okay when the records retrieved are between 0-300 records. However when I try to work with records over this number, 671 records to be exact, the browsers(IE,FF,Chrome,Opera) hang and it seems the javascript is taking up a lot of resources and the browsers become slow after the select option is finally generated after a 5 minute wait.... 
I am looking for a way to make this more efficient and prevent such hangups as I will work with records upto 5000

```
$("#idea_selectrel").on("change",function(){
       var attributeid = $("option:selected",this).val();
       $.post("/OCSRM/PopulateHTMLTablesServlet.do",{"attributeid":attributeid,"table":'idearelations'},function(data){
           if(!$.isEmptyObject(data))
           {
               $("#idea_selectrelvalue option:not(:first)").remove();
               var html='';
               var len = data.length;               
               for(var i=0,len = data.length; i<len; i++ )
               {
                   var relvalue = [data[i].relvalue];
                   var description = [data[i].description];
                   html +='<option value="'+relvalue+'">'+relvalue+' - '+description+'</option>';
                   $("#idea_selectrelvalue").append(html).show();
               }
           }
           else
           {
               alert('No data found.');

           }


       },'json');
       //alert(attributeid);

    });
```

Comment: 5000 dom elements is screaming for a re-think on the design of your interface. You should ideally be paging this on the server.

Comment: add the html to DOM after you are done constructing all of it instead of piece by piece

Comment: How do you expect users to cope with a dropdown containing 5000 options?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is building up a long string of HTML containing the options. It's *also* appending the string over and over again to the `<select>` element.

Move the `.append()` to *after* the loop:

```
           for(var i=0,len = data.length; i<len; i++ )
           {
               var relvalue = [data[i].relvalue];
               var description = [data[i].description];
               html +='<option value="'+relvalue+'">'+relvalue+' - '+description+'</option>';
           }
           $("#idea_selectrelvalue").append(html).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to test the code but from what I can tell you're not clearing the html variable inside the loop, currently, the html will be added recursively for every iteration, and every iteration is updating the DOM, which will get pretty large, fast.

I'm not sure if this is by design, but if it's not, try moving the append outside of the loop.

```
           var html='';
           var len = data.length;               
           for(var i=0,len = data.length; i<len; i++ )
           {
               var relvalue = [data[i].relvalue];
               var description = [data[i].description];
               html +='<option value="'+relvalue+'">'+relvalue+' - '+description+'</option>';
           }

           $("#idea_selectrelvalue").append(html).show();
```

Comment: Best to check that the exact same answer was not already posted (4 mins earlier) before posting :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of DOM elements that will be slow to load even if created without JS. Assuming you don't have a way to pre-generate the select on the server and send it down, you could try not appending the value in the loop. You could build out a string of option values and then, after the string is created, set the html of the select to the generated string. The DOM manipulation in the loop could be a culprit at that level. However, it is important to note that large or deeply nested DOM elements can be a performance concern regardless.